# Как сделать загрузку артифакта из TeamCity на сервер?

Tags: teamcity

Разбираюсь с TeamCity.
Сделал билд на создание у агента-1 артефактов, которые нужно загрузить на +10 серверов.

1. Не могу понять, подойдет ли мне TeamCity Professional, для большого кол-во серверов, если кол-во будет расти?
2. Мне понадобиться на каждый сервер установить агента и написать build для обновление файлов?
3. 3 build agents included - не очень понимаю, что это значит?

Answer (score 0):

Там же есть таск для того, чтобы выкладывать артифакты по SMB или SSH. На серверах для этого не нужен агент TC, соответственно, вам не нужны лицензии.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не очень понял, как вы предлагаете делать, прописать как цикл?
И как я понял, кол-во агентов может быть бесконечно?

Comment: Количество авторизованных агентов в бесплатной версии равно трем. Можете написать свой скрипт на скриптовом языке, можете создать 10 шагов для выкладывания на каждый сервер.

Comment: А не знаете другое открытое решение для обновления данных на сервере, имею ввиду готовое или около готовое?

Comment: Что вы хотите делать с этим артифактом?

Comment: все лишь заменить их на сервере и выполнить какие-нибудь действия через консоль, остановить запустить IIS либо обновить БД

Answer (score 0):

1. > Не могу понять, подойдет ли мне TeamCity Professional, для большого кол-во серверов, если кол-во будет расти?

```
Да, подойдет.
```

2. > Мне понадобиться на каждый сервер установить агента и написать build для обновление файлов?

   Нет, один агент может загружать файлы по ssh на любое количество серверов удаленно.
3. > 3 build agents included - не очень понимаю, что это значит?

   Простым языком: Это значит вы можете одновременно использовать до трех рабочих машин для выполнения заданий (билдов) тимсити. Ту же самую работу может выполнять и один агент, просто задачи (билды) будут складываться в очередь, которую будет разбирать агент. Для задачи загрузки файлов на удаленные сервера одного агента должно хватить с головой.